# Xcode - Time profiler and view user executed stacks?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

On older version of time profiler it was possible to view the amount of time lines of code would take to execute, or the user stack info. This info is not available anymore/

[image]

Instead this is what appears on the latest version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check seconde tab same with old version of Xcode:

[image]

If check it we will see:

[image]

And:

[image]

Hope this help!

Comment: still doesn't work :( All i see is memory locations, no class name or method name in the stack

Comment: @aryaxt Do you miss something? After select like above I can see same as you want. It weird. @_@

Comment: hmmmm I don't see any of that? are you running the latest version of xcode (7.1+)? yours look like how I used to have it?